# Time prediction using specialised setup in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, time-series, lstm, prediction

I'm working on a project where I have to predict the future states of a 1D vector with y entries. I'm trying to do this using an ANN setup with LSTM units in combination with a convolution layer. The method I'm using is based on the method they used in a ([pre-release paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.10123.pdf)). The suggested setup is as follows:

[image]

In the picture c is the 1D vector with y entries. The ANN gets the n previous states as an input and produces o next states as an output.

Currently, my ANN setup looks like this:

```
inputLayer = Input(shape = (n, y))
encoder = LSTM(200)(inputLayer)
x = RepeatVector(1)(encoder)
decoder = LSTM(200, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = Conv1D(y, 4, activation = 'linear', padding = 'same')(decoder)

model = Model(inputLayer, x)
```

Here n is the length of the input sequences and y is the length of the state array. As can be seen I'm repeating the d vector only 1 time, as I'm trying to predict only 1 time step in the future. Is this the way to setup the above mentioned network?

Furthermore, I have a numpy array (data) with a shape of (Sequences, Time Steps, State Variables) to train with. I was trying to divide this in randomly selected batches with a generator like this:

```
def BatchGenerator(batch_size, n, y, data):
        # Infinite loop.
    while True:
        # Allocate a new array for the batch of input-signals.
        x_shape = (batch_size, n, y)
        x_batch = np.zeros(shape=x_shape, dtype=np.float16)

        # Allocate a new array for the batch of output-signals.
        y_shape = (batch_size, 1, y)
        y_batch = np.zeros(shape=y_shape, dtype=np.float16)

        # Fill the batch with random sequences of data.
        for i in range(batch_size):
            # Select a random sequence
            seq_idx = np.random.randint(data.shape[0])
            # Get a random start-index.
            # This points somewhere into the training-data.
            start_idx = np.random.randint(data.shape[1] - n)
            # Copy the sequences of data starting at this 
            # Each batch inside x_batch has a shape of [n, y]
            x_batch[i,:,:] = data[seq_idx, start_idx:start_idx+n, :]
            # Each batch inside y_batch has a shape of [1, y] (as we predict only 1 time step in advance)
            y_batch[i,:,:] = data[seq_idx, start_idx+n, :]

        yield (x_batch, y_batch)
```

The problem is that it gives an error if I'm using a batch_size of more than 1. Could anyone help me to set this data up in a way that it can be used optimally to train my neural network?

The model is now trained using:

```
generator = BatchGenerator(batch_size, n, y, data)
model.fit_generator(generator = generator, steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch, epochs = epochs)
```

Thanks in advance!